# Jade converts & to &amp; when JavaScript is used

Tags: javascript, pug, html-entities, harp

I've just started using [Harp 0.30.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/harp) which comes with Jade installed as a pre-processor. So I'm just starting with Jade, too.

I have a folder containing a set of files with filenames like `This-is-an-MD-file.md`. With the `index.jade` file in this folder, I want to produce the following HTML output:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="This-is-an-MD-file.html">This is an MD file</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have understood enough about Jade and mixins to produce this...

```
- var trim = function(string) {
-   var index = string.lastIndexOf(".")
-   return string.substring(0, index).replace(/-/g, " ")
- }

mixin link(fileName)
  li
    a(href='#{fileName}') #{trim(fileName)}

ul
  for file in public._contents
    - if (file !== "index.html"){
      +link(file)
    -}
```

... which gives me what I want.

However, if I try to use `"&nbsp;"` instead of `" "` in the replace function, I see that the HTML output uses `&amp;` instead of the `&` character.

```html
<li>
  <a href="This-is-an-MD-file.html">
    This&amp;nbsp;is&amp;nbsp;and&amp;nbsp;MD&amp;nbsp;file
  </a>
</li>
```

Which is not what I want.

This happens just in the JavaScript function. If I use `&nbsp;` in the plain Jade markup section, like this...

```
p non&nbsp;breaking&nbsp;space
```

... the HTML is output exactly as expected.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to escape the `&` character in the JavaScript section so that it is not converted to an HTML entity?

Comment: it's called sanitizing, what if there will be: `<script>...</script>` in Your content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [unescaped string interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped) syntax (`!{variable}`) instead of the regular string interpolation syntax (`#{variable}`) in order to get those non-breaking spaces to render.

In your case:

```
a(href= fileName) !{trim(fileName)}
```

But keep in mind this word of warning from the [Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped):

> **Caution**
>
> Keep in mind that buffering unescaped content into your templates can be mighty risky if that content comes fresh from your users. Never trust user input!

Comment: I had seen the `!` but I hadn't tried putting it there. In this case, the input is the names of files on my development machine, so I'm the only user that I shouldn't be trusting.