# How to parse links (or any HTML tags) from external source (e.g. json) in re-useable pug template?

Tags: checkbox, pug

To my understanding, pug templtes are to be re-used. So I set up a collection for building forms and have `partials` like `input.pug`, `textarea.pug`, `checkbox.pug`, radio-buttons.pug`, etc.

In order to make sense of their reusability, they of course should show different text whenever they are used. Therefore I use `- locals.msg = Some custom Text` in the pug template that includes any of the form partials.

But as soon as it comes to provide more complex text that consists of links or contains styling elements (like `b` or a span tag with classes), the text is not parsed properly. This is what I have: a simple checkbox for GDPR acceptance that a user must click in a form. The explanation text is supposed to provide an external link to a page, where the user can read all about the site's data protection:

```
// parent pug template
div(class="[...]")

  - var form = { id: 'for-gdpr', txt: 'I have read <a href="#" target="_blank">GDPR</a> ...' }
  include ./form/checkbox.pug


// checkbox pug template
label(class="flex items-baseline block w-full")
  input(class="..." type="checkbox")
    div(class="...")= form.txt
```

Of course this does not generate a proper link, instead that a-tag is "written out".

I also tried splitting text like this:

```
- var form = { msg1: 'I have read ', msg2: 'a(class="..." href="..." target="_blank" data protextion ', msg: ' and concur.'}
```

but to no avail.

How would I have to prepare the text in order to then parse it properly in a pug template?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jade converts & to &amp; when JavaScript is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820158/jade-converts-to-amp-when-javascript-is-used)

Comment: You need to use the unescaped string interpolation syntax, as described in the answer to the question linked above.